# Unreal Engine: My game UI is not interactable, hover and click events not firing

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Been trying to crack this for days, nothing seems to let me interact with my game UI. I've set and unset player controller input modes, made a blank UI with a single button to make sure nothing is conflicting with it. Visibility is set correctly, and there's nothing else that could be blocking it. Widget Reflector however shows nothing in my viewport is hit testable. Here are some of my settings, blueprint setup and code:

```
void ABeneath_Director::SetInputMode( bool direct )
{
    APlayerController* PC = GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController();
    PC->bShowMouseCursor = !direct; 
    PC->bEnableClickEvents = !direct; 
    PC->bEnableMouseOverEvents = !direct;

    if( !direct )
    {
        FInputModeGameAndUI InputModeData;
        InputModeData.SetWidgetToFocus(CurrentHUD->TakeWidget());
        InputModeData.SetLockMouseToViewportBehavior(EMouseLockMode::DoNotLock);

        PC->SetInputMode(InputModeData);
    }
    else
    {
        FInputModeGameOnly InputModeData;
        PC->SetInputMode(InputModeData);
    }
}
```

[> Mouse Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yeFa.png)

[> Blueprint Button Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMfhw.png)

(Using UE5, but I don't think that's the issue. Cursor is visible.)

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and update your question accordingly.